# executing cypher queries from java program and obtaining output as a graph on the neo4j console

Tags: jakarta-ee, neo4j, cypher

I am making a maven dynamic web application on dijkstra's algorithm in eclipse neon. I want to showcase my result as a graph directly on the neo4j console by running cypher queries directly from the java program. The basic thing is that the graph is only meant for visualization purpose for the user. so, What kind of code should be written in the java program to execute the cypher query (eg: match(n) return n) directly on the console? There are a lot of APIs and codes on github but none of them provide a specific result to my problem. I am not using neo4j spring data model. I am using neo4j CE 3.1.3. How can this be done in the best possible manner?

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow take a tour Go through [How to Ask on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which helps you for more views and some Answers

Answer (score 0):

Since Neo4j only provides an API for the graph database and not for the browser for presenting purposes, I'd:

1. Show the whole graph in the Neo4j browser (running the query manually)
2. Run my Dijsktra algorithm from Java
3. Remove any edges which are not part of the shortest path
4. Show the new graph in the Neo4j browser (running the query manually)

If using the Neo4j browser is not a necessity, there are other [visualisation options](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/), especially the [Alchemy.js](http://graphalchemist.github.io/Alchemy/#/) option seems promising to showcase programming / graph database handling skills.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on alchemy.js. I am going to design the nodes and relationships using neo4j. But, I would like to execute the data visualization part using alchemy.js. Can you  please help with alchemy.js in java?

Comment: @AkshitaSrivastava: I'm not familiar with it, but as the name suggests, it's a JavaScript library. But according to their examples (http://graphalchemist.github.io/Alchemy/#/examples) you should be fine with simply providing the nodes and edges in the required JSON format from Java and setting it as the `dataSource` for Alchemy.js.